# No key value in JSON

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, json, web-services

**I am using the following code snippet for a `JSON` request.**

```
 <WebMethod(Description:="Gets the Categories")> _
    <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
    Public Function GetCategories() As String
        Using ds As DataSet = db.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.Text, "SELECT NodeID,NodeName FROM Nodes WHERE ParentID='1'")
            ' Create a multidimensional jagged array
            Dim JaggedArray As String()() = New String(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)() {}
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            For Each rs As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                JaggedArray(i) = New String() {rs("NodeName").ToString(), rs("NodeID").ToString()}
                i = i + 1
            Next

            ' Return JSON data
            Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer()
            Dim strJSON As String = js.Serialize(JaggedArray)
            Return strJSON
        End Using
    End Function
```

**Response I Get:**

```
<string xmlns="http://localhost:54511/">
[["Books","BK01"],["Computers","CO01"],["Gaming","GA01"],["Mobile & Accessories","MO01"]]
</string>
```

**Why dont i get the `key`??**

Eg:

```
<string xmlns="http://localhost:54511/">
[{"nodename":"Books","nodeid":"BK01"},{"nodename":"Computers","nodeid":"CO01"},{"nodename":"Gaming","nodeid":"GA01"},{"nodename":"Mobile & Accessories","nodeid":"MO01"}]
</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be because you are serializing an array not an object, not very familiar with vb.net but I believe what you're looking for is a `Dictionary( Of String, String)` and adding values to it as `dictionary.add('nodename', rs("NodeName").ToString()` ... and so on